# Filtering data from 2 table

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

Here I have 2 query variable for showing a different type of data,But i want to extract a particular data from first query ,which don't have  reference in second query
I have the following code,but it does not work properly as.first query variable is used to join  4 table like A,B,C,D and Second Query variable Join table A and B.Here i want a data from First variable and it don't have any reference in second table

```
 public List<ProductEntityList> GetProductListRegister()
 {
     var ProductList1 = new List<ProductEntityList>();
     var ProductList = new List<ProductEntityList>();
     var finalList = new List<ProductEntityList>();

     try
     {
         using (HabitGreen01Entities ob = new HabitGreen01Entities())
         {
             var list1 = from ctr in ob.TblCreateUsers
                         join shp in ob.TblShopMasters
                         on ctr.id equals shp.Fk_CreateUser_Id
                         join prd in ob.TblProductMaster01
                         on shp.id equals prd.FK_ShopMaster_Id    
                         select new ProductEntityList
                         {
                             Id = prd.id,
                             Name = prd.Name,
                             ShopName = shp.Name,
                             UserName = ctr.Name
                         };

             ProductList1 = list1.ToList();

             var temp = from pd in ob.TblProductMaster01
                        join cr in ob.TblAccountSettings
                        on pd.id equals cr.f_productmaster01Id
                        select new ProductEntityList
                        {
                            Id = (int)cr.f_productmaster01Id,
                            Name=pd.Name                                      
                        };

              ProductList = temp.ToList();

              var temp1 = from item in ProductList1
                          where !ProductList.Contains(x=>item.Id)
                          select new ProductEntityList
                          {
                              Id = item.Id,
                              Name = item.Name,
                              ShopName = item.ShopName,
                              UserName = item.UserName
                          };

              finalList = temp1.ToList();

              // var temp1= ProductList1.Select(f=>f.Id).Intersect(ProductList.Select(b=>b.Id));    
              //finalList = matches.ToList();
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          throw e;
      }

      return (finalList);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = ProductList1.Where(p => !ProductList.Any(p2 => p2.Id== p.Id));
 finalList = result.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var temp1 = from item in ProductList1
                          where !ProductList.Select(c=>c.Id).Contains(item.Id)
                          select new ProductEntityList
                          {
                              Id = item.Id,
                              Name = item.Name,
                              ShopName = item.ShopName,
                              UserName = item.UserName
                          };
```

You can write directly:

```
var finalList = (from item in ProductList1
                          where !ProductList.Select(c=>c.Id).Contains(item.Id)
                          select new ProductEntityList
                          {
                              Id = item.Id,
                              Name = item.Name,
                              ShopName = item.ShopName,
                              UserName = item.UserName
                          }).ToList();
```